# Dual bootable Windows VM

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, virtualization, gpu

I want to use Linux (Arch) as my main operating system. But sometimes I need to use software which is only available on Windows (and not supported by Wine) or I want to play some games. So I found two possible solutions:

1. Use Windows inside a VM

   - Does not offer the needed performance for games (GPU)
   - I could use GPU passthrough, but this requires a second GPU and it's likely 
     not to work correctly on most hardware
2. Dual-boot Linux and Windows

   - I have to reboot every time I want to switch the OS => I cannot use Windows 
     and Linux software at the same time

Is there maybe the possibility to create a dual-bootable VM so that I can use Windows software while I booted Linux. And game on a dual-booted Windows? Or do you have another idea how to achieve my goals.

Comment: Windows host with a Linux VM? If that's not an option, I think you've exhausted your choices.

Comment: Sadly this is not an option, because I want to use my linux environment to work (for example with i3 would have problems using the Windows Key for mappings)

Comment: What stops you from having two windows installations? One dual-booted for games, the other inside a VM for your work software.

Comment: Yeah if there is no other solution I will do it like this. I just don't wanted to maintain two installations.

Comment: `it's likely to not work correctly on most hardware` is unlikely true for pcie passthrough these days

Comment: If you want to use both operating systems at the same time, you need to use virtualizing software. I use VMware. There is  Hyper-V and others. I have a Windows 10 host and can run Kali Linux, Ubuntu and Windows 7 all at the same time. Best approach in my view.

Comment: At the moment I'm using KVM / Libvirt and I'm very happy with it. I hoped I could also directly boot the system. (I use a physical drive for my windows vm)

Answer (score 1):

You might have look at KVM a kernel level hypervisor for linux systems. 
As far as i know it should be light weight enough to enable gaming.

There might be other bare metal hypervisors that allow you to boot 2 oses simontaniously but i dont know about any from the top of my head.